# raw_input recognizes ^? but not ^H

Tags: python, linux, raw-input

I'm trying to get the backspace key to work in a python script that I have. Basically, the code in the script looks something like:

```
print("Please type the character 'h':")
choice = raw_input()
if choice == 'h':
        print("Thanks.")
else:
        print("You input the wrong character.")
```

Now, obviously, this is a toy script, but I'm having difficulty getting `raw_input()` to do what I want. For example, if I run the script, type `a`, then realize that I've typed the wrong character, and so hit backspace, I get:

```
Please type the character 'h':
a^H
```

But, if I type `^?` instead, it translates to the correct command:

```
Please type the character 'h':
<<< CURSOR HERE
```

So, my question is this: I think this has to do with my linux environment - i.e. I think I need to load a keymap that tells linux that I want it to output `^?` when the backspace key is hit, but I don't know why it seems to work in all other programs (even the python interpreter, surprisingly - if I manually put that code into the python interpreter, it works as expected!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What terminal program are you using? It may have a setting with which you can control how your backspace key is interpreted.

In gnome-terminal, if you click on `Edit>Profile Preferences>Compatibility`, 
you can tell gnome-terminal to send `ASCII DEL` instead of Ctrl-h when the backspace key is pressed.
[image]

---

Otherwise, I think you can fix your keymap with something like

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace"
```

My memory is rusty, however. Please consult the [HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html) and/or [this guide](http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard.html) for details.

Comment: Well, I was using Gnome-Terminal, so this suggestion solved my problem. I was just wondering why python interpreted it one way in the terminal, and another way in the interpreter.

Comment: BTW - Thanks for the image. It was very easy to find that pref in the gnome-terminal options. I appreciate you taking the time to take a screenshot - it saved me time!